# How to reuse property fetched using Reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

```
private static string GenerateStr<T>(IList<T> obj, string propName)
{
  string str = string.Empty;
  foreach(var o in obj)
  {
      str += o.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(o, null); 
          //is there a way to only call above line once, then call
          // str =+ o.myStrProp over the course of the iteration?

  }
  return str;
}
```

Is there a way to be able to **reuse the fetched property** to refrain from relying on *Reflection* to do it again for me. Thanks!

Comment: o.GetType() can be stored as a temp variable, but different properties must be reflected respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What you acutally asked for

Well, if you want to stick to the methods signature (`string`: `List<T>`, `string`) then you at least could reuse the fetched `PropertyInfo` like that:

```
private static string GenerateStr<T>(IEnumerable<T> obj, string propName)
{
    var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propName);
    string str = string.Empty;

    foreach(var o in obj)
    {
        str += propertyInfo.GetValue(o, null);
    }

    return str;
}
```

This can even be shortened using LINQ:

```
private static string GenerateStr<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, string propName)
    {
        var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propName);

        return string.Concat(list.Select(o => propertyInfo.GetValue(o, null)));
    }
```

### IMO Better Approach

Another and maybe even better way would be to pass sth. like a Member Expression instead of a `string` as the second argument:

```
private string GenerateStrBetter<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, object> func)
{
    var res = string.Empty;

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        res += func(item).ToString();
    }

    return res;
}
```

This should be even faster since it doesn't use reflection at all. Also, it can be rewritten to a one-liner ;) :

```
private string GenerateStrBetter<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, object> func)
{
    return string.Concat(list.Select(item => func(item).ToString()));
}
```

#### Usage

```
var result = GenerateStrBetter(list, item => item.Text);
```

Not only is this faster, it also supports you during development by applying IntelliSense and avoiding Magic strings which migth be forgotten once somebody refactores your Property-Names or sth.

Comment: Thanks! Never thought a measly typeof would do the trick, lol

Comment: Check my Edit, this even gives you intellisense and refactoring support w/o magic strings...

Comment: Thanks again! I ended up using your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1):

This example, inspired by [thibaud60](http://thibaud60.blogspot.sk/2010/10/fast-property-accessor-without-dynamic.html), creates delegate, that is super fast comparing to Reflection used every iteration.

So all you have to do, is to call: `var accessor = PropertyHelper.CreateAccessor(typeof(T).GetProperty(propName));` before the loop begins. To get the value you just call `var value = accessor.GetValue(o);`

```
public static class PropertyHelper
{
    public static IPropertyAccessor CreateAccessor(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        if (propertyInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyInfo");

        return (IPropertyAccessor)Activator.CreateInstance(
            typeof(PropertyWrapper<,>).MakeGenericType
                (propertyInfo.DeclaringType, propertyInfo.PropertyType), propertyInfo);
    }
}

public interface IPropertyValueAccessor
{
    PropertyInfo PropertyInfo { get; }

    string Name { get; }
    object GetValue(object source);
}

public interface IPropertyAccessor
{
    PropertyInfo PropertyInfo { get; }

    string Name { get; }
    object GetValue(object source);
    void SetValue(object source, object value);
}

internal class PropertyWrapper<TObject, TValue> : IPropertyAccessor
{
    private PropertyInfo _propertyInfo;
    private Func<TObject, TValue> _getMethod;
    private Action<TObject, TValue> _setMethod;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructeur public
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyInfo">la propriété à encapsulé
    public PropertyWrapper(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        _propertyInfo = propertyInfo;

        MethodInfo mGet = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod(true);
        MethodInfo mSet = propertyInfo.GetSetMethod(true);

         // Rq : on peut par se biais acceder aussi aux accesseur privé
        //      tous les aspects liés à la sécurité est donc pris en charge par CreateDelegate
        //      et non à chaque appel à GetMethod/SetMethod

        _getMethod = (Func<TObject, TValue>)Delegate.CreateDelegate
                (typeof(Func<TObject, TValue>), mGet);
        _setMethod = (Action<TObject, TValue>)Delegate.CreateDelegate
                (typeof(Action<TObject, TValue>), mSet);
    }

    object IPropertyValueAccessor.GetValue(object source)
    {
        return _getMethod((TObject)source);
    }
    void IPropertyAccessor.SetValue(object source, object value)
    {
        _setMethod((TObject)source, (TValue)value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Voir <see cref="IPropertyAccessor.Name">
    /// </see></summary>
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _propertyInfo.Name;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Voir <see cref="IPropertyAccessor.PropertyInfo">
    /// </see></summary>
    public PropertyInfo PropertyInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return _propertyInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options here - the first one is to use reflection, but not retrieve the property in each iteration:

```
static string GenerateStrReflection<T>(IList<T> obj, string propName)
{
    var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propName);

    return string.Concat(obj.Select(o => property.GetValue(o)));
}
```

Note that using `String.Concat` is a faster and more memory-efficient approach to combining strings than using the `+=` operator, since that will create a new string each iteration!

If you want to further improve the speed of this method when executing on large lists, you may consider compiling a Lambda expression:

```
static string GenerateStrExpression<T>(IList<T> obj, string propName)
{
    // o
    var oParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "o");
    // o.Property
    var propertyExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(oParameter, propName);
    // cast to object ensure we don't get compiler errors when creating the lambda
    var cast = Expression.Convert(propertyExpression, typeof(object));
    // o => (object)o.Property;
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(cast, oParameter).Compile();

    return string.Concat(obj.Select(lambda));
}
```

This works well on large lists, but the `Compile` method has a very significant overhead (see numbers below). We can ensure the `Compile` only happens once by letting our function return a compiled function to operate against the list:

```
static Func<IList<T>, string> GenerateStrExpressionCached<T>(string propName)
{
    var oParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "o");
    var propertyExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(oParameter, propName);
    var cast = Expression.Convert(propertyExpression, typeof(object));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(cast, oParameter).Compile();
    // here we return a lambda to operate against the list.
    return list => string.Concat(list.Select(lambda));
}
```

This allows us to cache the function, example:

```
var cachedFunc = GenerateStrExpressionCached<MyClass>("MyProperty");
List<MyClass> myList = ...;
string result = cachedFunc(myList);
```

To put some evidence behind this, below numbers are for `1000` iterations, in `Release` mode (optimized code). As you can see, the list size is a big factor in which method is faster. Note that the 3rd column cheats a little, since it doesn't consider the call to `GenerateStrExpressionCached<MyClass>("MyProperty")` in the execution time.

```
List Size      Reflection (ms)     Expression (ms)   Expression Cached (ms)
1              0                   127               0
100            20                  133               4
10000          2000                600               470
```

The test code:

```
const int ListSize = 10000; //change to what you want to measure
const int Iterations = 1000;
var list = new List<MyClass>(ListSize);
for (var i = 0; i < ListSize; i++)
    list.Add(new MyClass());

//initialize the cached function
var cachedFunc = GenerateStrExpressionCached<MyClass>("MyProperty");

var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (var i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
    GenerateStrExpression(list, "MyProperty");
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

sw.Restart();
for (var i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
    GenerateStrReflection(list, "MyProperty");
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

sw.Restart();
for (var i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
    cachedFunc(list);
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

...

class MyClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; } = "Hello World";
}
```